# How to use a JavaScript variable in a string

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation

This is my code:

```js
axios.post(currentUrl + this.data_source_url + "/create", {
    'date': this.item_data.date,
    'type_id': this.item_data.type_id,
    'value': this.item_data.value,
     this.id_name: this.id,  <------
    '_method': 'post',
});
```

I tried `'String text ${expression}'` but this didn't work

Is it possible to use the `this.id_name` variable as a string in this axios call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [computed property name](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript):

```js
axios.post(currentUrl + this.data_source_url + '/create', {
  date: this.item_data.date,
  type_id: this.item_data.type_id,
  value: this.item_data.value,
  [this.id_name]: this.id, // <------
  _method: 'post'
})
```